# accessing basic information with now access token

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i'm trying to get user's public information (name, photo, gender, profile link).

as i seen in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/ to get this information i don't need any access token.

i'm using the facebook.php sdk to connect to facebook as written in the example: 
https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/blob/master/examples/example.php

for some reason it always ask me to get access token for basic information, although all i need is public information...

how can i get the public information only with no access token ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get public information without an access token, just go to the graph itself.

Try https://graph.facebook.com/4 for an example.

Comment: but i want to get the user who use my site.. and when i'm trying
https://graph.facebook.com/me it ask for accesstoken

Comment: Strange, it does not ask me for any access tokens going to https://graph.facebook.com/4, I even used a browser that had no facebook credentials to use too.

Comment: you're right when you're using a specific link, but i want the get the public information on a /me user - it means, every user how's in my site (if he's on facebook and logged in offcuarse)

Comment: The user must accept (authorize) your application for you to get a user access token to be able to specify "me" rather than their user id.

Comment: and if the user is already logged in to facebook, isn't there a way i can get his user id ?

Comment: Yes if the user is already logged into facebook, when they accept (authorize) your app, you can get it.

Answer (score 0):

To get the information from the user, the user has to grant you their information. This is done by them logging in to your site via their facebook account. By implementing the Facebook PHP SDK on your site you can use the function getLoginUrl() to provide the login url to the users. When they've logged in, they'll be sent back to your site with their id available. You can then use the api() method to query the graph for the information you want. Remember that for all information that is not public, you'll need to ask for privileges when they connect their account.

If you don't have their access token, you can't get information from them. You'll need to know who the users are in order to query for information. But once you've got their access token you can store basic information in your own database so that you don't have to query the graph next time.

Comment: but lets assume i know the user is logged into facebook because he got into my site from facebook.
can i just get his public information ?

Comment: No. Your application needs authorization to retrieve information about the user, and the user itself has to give you that authorization.